# Grafana templating: Regex for Prometheus label_values variables

Tags: grafana, prometheus, grafana-templating

I am trying to setup templating in Grafana using the **label_values** function.
The documentation specifies the possibility to query label_values like:

```
label_values(metric, label)
```

In my use case there are two main metric groups with names similar to:

- app1_current_sensor1
- app1_current_sensor2
- app2_current_sensor2
- app2_current_sensor3

Each of them has a label named **'uid'**.
I'm looking to use the above query to filter **only the user ids of the 'app1'** on one dashboard and 'app2' on another dashboard.

I've tried

```
label_values(app1_current_sensor1, uid)
```

But if for some reason sensor1 does not send data for a while I won't be seeing any more user ids on the dashboard even though sensor2 is sending data.

Would it be possible to use a regex as input for the metric variable?
Something like this would work for me:

```
label_values(metric=~(app1_[^\s]+), uid)
```

But I'm not sure if this is possible in Grafana.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following expression selects all metrics that have a name starting with `job_` and have label `method="GET"`

```
{__name__=~"job_.*", method="GET"}
```

To get all metrics whose name start with `app1_` use

```
{__name__=~"app1_.*"}
```

To get all metrics whose name start with `app1_` and `uid` equal to some specific value, use

```
 {__name__=~"app1_.*", uid="value"}
```

Comment: Awesome! **__name__** was exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you

Using this with label_values as follows: `label_values({__name__=~"app1_.*"}, uid)`

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-labels-from-legacy-metric-names

Comment: Hi, what is `name` here? is it a predefined keyword?

Comment: Yes, `__name__` is a internal label in Prometheus: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/